# Linux browse and open network files with command line

Tags: linux, command-line, network-shares

I'm new to Linux. I have a Windows network connected to a Linux computer. When I try to browse Windows files from windows managers in Linux, it asks for user name, work group name and password.

The address of computer network is something like this: `smb://computer-name/folder`

I want to access my network folders and files using command line. I have searched a little bit but I didn't find anything.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `smbclient` and `smbtree` tools provided by Samba to explore the network, browse shares and copy files back and forth between a remote host and your local system.

If you want to mount a SMB share at a directory mountpoint in your local file system, you would use the `cifs` file system type, for example as shown [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157140/11751).